# Add variable to query string SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

Please support me to add variable to query string.

I tried this code

```
create trigger UPLtoTOTAL on UP_PLAN
for insert
as
begin
    set nocount on

    declare @code nvarchar(10)
    declare @qty decimal(18,9)
    declare @dd int

    select @code = inserted.CODE, 
           @qty = inserted.QTY, 
           @dd = inserted.dd 
    from inserted

    declare @sqlstr nvarchar(1000)
    set @sqlstr = 'insert into TOTAL(CODE, COL2) values(' + @code + ',' + @qty + ')'
    exec(@sqlstr)
end
```

But I get an error from SQL Server:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric.

Please help me modify that code.

Thank you!

Comment: This code is so wrong. 1) SQL Server trigger fire per statement not per row 2) Unnecessary use of dynamic SQL 3) Wrong datatypes and  implicit conversions 4) Total table looks like some preaggregation (maybe materialiazed view would be better solution)

Answer (score 0):

If you make it

```
create trigger UPLtoTOTAL on UP_PLAN 
for insert as 
begin 
set nocount on
insert into TOTAL(CODE, COL2) values(inserted.CODE, inserted.QTY)
end
```

this makes the assumption that the table your inserting to and the table your triggering into have the same data types.